# Where did the names Siegfried and Tristan Farnon come from?

Tags: name-significance, james-herriot

The British vet and writer [Alfred Wight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Herriot) is best known for his series of semi-autobiographical stories written under the pen name James Herriot, recounting details of his experience as a country vet in North Yorkshire. In these books, he himself appears as James/Jim Herriot, rather than his real name of Alfred/Alf Wight, and his friends [Donald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Sinclair_(veterinary_surgeon)) and [Brian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Sinclair_(veterinary_surgeon)) Sinclair appear as Siegfried and Tristan Farnon.

The name James Herriot apparently comes from a [Scottish goalkeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Herriot) whom he saw on television. What about the names Siegfried and Tristan Farnon? Where did these names come from and why?

Comment: In universe (in the narative) it was stated that Siegfreid & Tristans mother was a big fan of Wagner, hence the naming of her sons.
In real life, no idea I'm afraid...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @rand-althor for finding the citation!

[This article, an interview with the author](http://newsok.com/article/2114866) includes a brief explanation of the choices:

> **Siegfried** was taken from the heroic character of German legend who had inspired composer Richard Wagner. The strong personality traits of his associate had not been lost on Herriot.
>   "After I decided on Siegfried for Donald, **Tristan** became the obvious name for Brian," the writer said. Tristan was a young romantic. That seemed to fit perfectly.

It turned out that my “Norse” recollection wasn’t completely off-beam either: the German **Siegfried** character is, it seems, basically the same as the Norse [**Sigurd**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigurd) (Wikipedia). These legends (in their German version) inspired Wagner's series of four operas, [***Der Ring des Nibelungen*** (a.k.a. **The Ring Cycle**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Ring_des_Nibelungen), of which [***Siegfried***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegfried_(opera)) is the third.

The **Tristan** character on the other hand is found in another Wagner opera, [***Tristan und Isolde***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristan_und_Isolde) (English translation left as an exercise for the reader), which he composed as a diversion after completing the first two acts of *Siegfried*.